# SliderExtender causing 0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio, ajaxcontroltoolkit

At first, I got this error on start up but I found a few articles where people encountered this problem and I added the fixes:

1. Make sure this is in your .aspx

   `<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajax" %>`
2. Change your ScriptManager to this:

   `<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager" runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>`

After that, my webpage displayed fine.

I want to add a slider to my page so I added the following code:

```
            <asp:TextBox ID="TimeSelect" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px" Text="00:40"></asp:TextBox>
            <br /> <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TimeSelect_Bounds" runat="server" Width="30px"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajax:SliderExtender ID="TimeSelect_SliderExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="TimeSelect" BoundControlID="TimeSelect_Bounds" Steps="5">
            </ajax:SliderExtender>
```

Now the project is getting the same error again.

Am I using the SliderExtender incorrectly? I was trying to follow tutorials online. I found one using a Label as the bound instead of a TextBox, but the error appeared when I did that as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the past when I've encountered this error it was because I was using an alternate tool script manager from a third party library.

I would try confirming that you have the correct version of the AjaxControlLibrary referenced in your project.

If that does not work try creating a test website with all unneeded references stripped out so you can isolate this scenario. There may be some odd ball reference that is somehow causing a problem or some other control may be causing the problem even though you are getting the error on the slider extender.

Comment: How do I check what version I have? I'm pretty sure I have the latest one because I downloaded it from the website last week.